# Registering instances from property of other registered types?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Is there a better way to code this dependency on **Configuration**, how can I register an object which is provided by a property of another registered object?

I have a configuration object which exposes a configuration property for each service. I'd like to initialize those services based on their configuration object interface.

```
void RegisterConfiguration(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    var config = new Configuration();
    builder.RegisterInstance(config).As<IConfiguration>();

    builder.RegisterInstance(config.Service1Configuration).As<IService1Configuration>();
    builder.RegisterInstance(config.Service2Configuration).As<IService2Configuration>();
}
```

*Note: I also thought to include ".ExternallyOwned()", but omitted it here because that wasn't part of the question.*

Then for each ServiceX I have the following constructor:

```
public Service1(IService1Configuration config)
{
    this.config = config;
}
```

I would like to be able to simply Register **Configuration** and have Autofac somehow instantiate **Configuration** for me.

I was thinking of a factory for the service registrations but I wasn't sure if I could resolve the **Configuration** object in a factory.

Any ideas how I can make this less explicit and use more of Autofac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of the `Register` method is a `IComponentContext`. It means that you can use it to resolve some dependencies.

example :

```
void RegisterConfiguration(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<Configuration>()
           .As<IConfiguration>()
           .SingleInstance();

    builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<Iconfiguration>()
                           .Service1Configuration)
           .As<IService1Configuration>();
    builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IConfiguration>()
                           .Service2Configuration)
           .As<IService2Configuration>();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I missed thanks. One question, would it be wrong to add .SingleInstance() to the second two registrations?

Comment: Adding `.SingleInstance()` will cache the result whereas if you omit it the property will be called each time the service is resolved which could be great if your configuration change over time. I expect a tiny performance gain and slightly larger memory footprint with `SingleInstance()`